# Most efficient way to extract data from multiple .xlsx files using Excel Interop in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, interop, excel-interop

I have just started getting into Excel Interop and was wondering how I could improve the performance of my application by implementing either multithreading or multitasking.

My code looks something like this atm:

```
foreach(var path in arrayOfExcelFilePaths){
    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
}
foreach(var wb in excelApp.Workbooks){
    //Read stuff and maybe write stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance for anybody looking into this.

Comment: I don't know if multithreading will imprve the read times if you're using a single instance of Excel. You could try creating a separate excel application for each workbook. Also, I'd try making sure my read operations are optimised before trying multithreading as that is usually the cause of poor exel interop IO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean exactly by optimizing read operations?

Comment: What I mean is that your read operation should read all the data in one go into a an array. This is usually quite fast even for very large datasets. The slowness of interop is mainly due the marshalling between managed/unmanaged code and the IPC, so reducing the number of marshalling operations usually speeds things up considerably. If you like I can answer with more detail but I'd ask you to update  your answer with some code of the read/write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Interop is a bad idea in general. The execution of your code won’t differ much from its equivalent written in a VBA macro, because Interop simply runs the Excel process in the background and replicates its functionality 1-to-1.

Try OfficeOpenXML or any other library that allows you manipulate the content of excel sheets without running MS Excel as Interop does.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use the [EPPlus 5](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) library, which is a newer version of the [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) library. Its fast and reliable, I've been using it for years without any issues.